# Mef instance creation

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mef

I am currently involved in designing an SOA application using mef. I have a doubt with instance creation. What I find is the instance can be created by two ways:
(i) container matches the import with available export and creates instance
(ii) Using getexportedvalue() also creates an instance.
So when do I need to what approach. Means when the service instance lives for the whole lifetime of the application can I take 1st approach because the object is available in the container.
 And when the service is used for short time can I use the second approach and dispose it.

Comment: _Services_ in _Managed Extensibility Framework_ (`MEF`) are not the same as services in _Service Orientated Architecture_ (`SOA`)

Comment: May be iam wrong in mentioning as soa. I am creating a loosely couple application using MEF. Can you please help in understanding the difference between the 2 types of instance creation which i have mentioned above. IS there any drawback in using GetExportedvalue to create instances

Comment: Check out the answer [here for more info on lifetime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18314865/mef-difference-between-getexportedvalue-and-satisfyimports)